# how can we apply threshold effect on png image using php

Tags: imagemagick, effect, threshold

I have some greyscaled png image or colorful images. i want to apply the threshold effect using php language.
I am still looking for the solution.

Comment: See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thresholdimage.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function thresholdimage($imagePath, $threshold, $channel) {
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $imagick->thresholdimage($threshold * \Imagick::getQuantum(), $channel);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}

?>
```